# Sass @for loop - from one color to another color

Tags: css, for-loop, sass

I need to create a list of css background colors gradually getting darker to reach a destination darkness. I know it's possible to use the technique stated here: [Sass: Change color with @for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582085/sass-change-color-with-for-loop)
But what I want to modulate from one color **to** another color. Not just make the color darker and darker.

I have a variable number of items and would like the background color to move from white to black. Basically a stepped gradient with a beginning and end color defined.

So if I had three items I would want the output to be something like this:

```
.class1 {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.class2 {
  background-color: #808080; // 50% brightness
}
.class3 {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

If I had five items it would look something like this:

```
.class1 {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.class2 {
  background-color: #bfbfbf; // 75% brightness
}
.class3 {
  background-color: #808080; // 50% brightness
}
.class4 {
  background-color: #404040; // 25% brightness
}
.class5 {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

The beginning and ending colors should always be the same, but the middle colors need to automatically adjust depending on the total of items in the loop.

I don't know if something like this is even possible with Sass??

Comment: If you want the background colour to change from white to black than the example that you linked to should work for you, as you can start with #fff and it will darken it until it is black. However if you want it to change from say red to blue than i'm not sure, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function you're needing here is `mix()`;

```
$color-1: white;
$color-2: black;

$steps: 5;

@for $i from 0 to $steps {
    .class-#{$i + 1} {
        background: mix($color-1, $color-2, percentage($i / ($steps - 1)));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.class-1 {
  background: black;
}

.class-2 {
  background: #3f3f3f;
}

.class-3 {
  background: #7f7f7f;
}

.class-4 {
  background: #bfbfbf;
}

.class-5 {
  background: white;
}
```

http://sassmeister.com/gist/d0fc452765908aac2617

Want them in the reverse order?  Just swap the colors.